# POST JSON data to PHP via C# and store values in MYSQL

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json

My Class in C# which should be send to PHP:

```
MyData data = new MyData();
data.Name = "MyName";
data.Type = "MyType";
data.ID = 1;
data.Description = "MyLongDescription...";
```

How do I send it to PHP via C# in JSON format? And how do I retrieve it in PHP?
The next step should be to insert the submitted data/values into a MySQL DB.

C# -> Send some JSON Data to PHP -> Write JSON Data to MYSQL DB via PHP

Sample Database:
MyData(varchar Name, varchar Type, int ID, varchar Description)

My current PHP Code:

```
$json = json_decode($input,true);

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$connection)
{
     die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("MyDataDB", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO MyData (Name, Type, OtherID, Description) 
VALUES('$json[Name]','$json[Type]','$json[ID]','$json[Description]')");
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: serialize data which should be send over the wire (create wcf) and use php to consume this service. http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2007/09/17/using-wcf-services-with-php.aspx

Comment: This question is overly broad. You've got several pretty big and **very distinct** tasks here (generating JSON, sending JSON over HTTP, receiving JSON over HTTP, parsing JSON, inserting data into a database). Put some effort into it, and then ask a **focused** question if you get stuck.

Comment: My problem is the C# part. I have to post the JSON data and a PHP parameter called "key" to make sure the user is authorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# code to encode:

```
var jsonSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = jsonSerializer.Serialize(yourCustomObject);
```

PHP code to decode:

```
$decoded = json_decode($received_json_string);
```

What have you tried, by the way?

Comment: I've tried the PHP part. But I don't know the best way to do it in C#.

Comment: At first encode your object as in given example and send using HttpWebRequest

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this, but to Quentin's point, you've got a lot going on.

There is no direct interop between C# and PHP so you'd need to expose a web service from PHP and consume it in your C#.  Better yet, have the C# save directly to mysql and don't worry about interop.